# VBA: Adaptive Selection of Rows, Columns, Range by Variable

Tags: excel, vba

I had a hard time selecting a specific headline. Nevertheless I hope someone is able to help me out.

I know that I can reference a Range via a String like this:

```
    Dim Str as String

    Str = "A1:A10"

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Table1").Range(Str).Select
    [...]
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Table2").Range(Str).Select
    [...]
```

But is it also possible to address a specific Range by putting the whole statement between the two dots like 'Range("A1:A10")' into a variable?

It would be handy since I often copy and paste code and sometimes I need to reference 'Rows(1:5)', sometimes 'Columns(A:E)', or a specific 'Range("A1:A10")'. Then I need to go through the whole code and replace these parts.

It would be great to just define this part within a variable in the beginning and use it throughout the script. Something like

```
    Dim Rfrc As String

    Rfrc = Rows("1:5")
or  Rfrc = Columns("A:E")
or  Rfrc = Range("A1:A10")

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Table1").Rfrc.Select
    [...]
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Table2").Rfrc.Select
    [...]
```

This is really my first question here and I hope you could help me out. So far I was always able to find answers to all my questions here, but this time I couldn't.

Answer (score 1):

*"But is it also possible to address a specific Range by putting a whole statement like 'Range("A1:A10")' into a variable?"*

Yes - a `Range` variable, a fundamental part of the Excel VBA toolkit. Instead of referencing a range by its address, `Set` and then reference a `Range` variable directly.

```
Sub WorkWithRanges()
    Dim rng As Range

    ' Work with a specific range, rows or columns
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set rng = .Range("A1:A10")
        Set rng = .Rows("1:5")
        Set rng = .Columns("A:E")
    End With
End Sub
```

Noting that you normally don't need to `Select` ranges to work with them and you want to always fully qualify what `Worksheet` they are on - i.e. try to avoid `ActiveSheet`.

---

**Edit 1**

If you're looping through sheets and it's the same `Range` on each sheet, set the `Range` using one reference.

```
Sub DimARangeOnceOnly()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws
            ' It's the same Range on each Worksheet
            ' And if I need to update the reference I only need to do it once
            Set rng = .Range("A1:A10")
            Set rng = .Rows("1:5")
            Set rng = .Columns("A:E")
            ' ...
        End With
    Next ws
End Sub
```

If you want to define a reference at the beginning and use it later, here's a `String`-based approach.

```
Sub UseAStringForARangeReference()
    Dim rowRfrc As String
    Dim colRfrc As String
    Dim rngRfrc As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    rowRfrc = "1:5"
    colRfrc = "A:E"
    rngRfrc = "A1:A10"

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws
            Set rng = .Range(rngRfrc)
            Set rng = .Rows(rowRfrc)
            Set rng = .Columns(colRfrc)
        End With
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. I maybe couldn't state my issue correctly. I know about that option. But i would also like to use Row, Columns sometimes instead of Range. Is that possible. Also the specific Range appears on different sheets in the code. So I can't just set a Range like this since it is always linked to a specific sheet, or?

Comment: Rows and Columns are ranges too... But when you say "Then I need to go through the whole code and replace these parts" - sounds like more of an overall design issue. If the specific Range appears on different sheets, when you loop through each sheet you can "reset" the `Range`, with only one reference to it in your code.

Comment: If you have working code but are trying to improve it, maybe head over to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) - as your question is, it's hard to really nail down your issue.